# Python on-the-fly compression library

Tags: python, http, zip, compression, lzma

Is there any Python library for creating compressed files on-the-fly so I can start sending the file while it is compressing. Right now, I am doing this:

```py
mydata=zlib.compress(open('files/SpeedTest_16MB.dat', 'rb').read(), zlib.Z_BEST_COMPRESSION)
result = requests.post("http://localhost/", data=mydata)
print result.status_code
```

This code sequence first compresses the file and then sends it. Is there any way to do this simultaneously and to transmit while compressing. I am concerned about the compression ratio also

Comment: Check out zipstream in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55516204/5008284).

Comment: Thank you. I will try that out